# i want to remove an element from my vector in an operator opverload function

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

i want to remove an element from a vector in an operator overloading function, ,i tried to use vector.erease but i get an error.

this is Dict class header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template <class K, class V>
class Dict {
protected:
    vector<K> keys;
    vector<Node<V>> values;
public:
    Dict();
    V& operator[](const K &str);
};
```

this is dict class cpp:

```
#include "Dict.h"
template <class K, class V>
Dict<K,V>::Dict() {};

template <typename K, typename  V>
V& Dict<K,V>::operator[](const K &str)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < this->keys.size(); i++)
    {
        if(this->keys[i] == str)
        {
            return this->values[i].value;
        }
    }
    this->keys.push_back(str);
    this->values.push_back(Node<V>());

    for(int i = 0; i < this->keys.size(); i++){
        Node<V> n = this->values[i];
        if(n.value == 0)
        {
        this->keys.erase(this->keys.begin() + i);
        this->values.erase(this->values.begin() + i);

        }

    }
    return this->values.back().value;
}

template class Dict<string, int>;
template class Dict<string, double>;\
```

this is node header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class V>
class Node {
protected:
    Node& operator=(const V& val);
public:
    V value;
};
```

this is node cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"
template <typename  V>
Node<V>& Node<V>::operator=(const V &dict) {
    this->value = dict;
    return *this;
}
```

and this is the main:

```
int main() {
    Dict<string, int> d1;
    Dict<string,double> d2;
    d1["a"] = 5;
    d1["b"];
    d1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

this should print a,5
but instead it prints a very long red error

```
*** Error in `/home/giftsky/CLionProjects/Dictionary/cmake-build-debug/Dictionary': double free or corruption (out):
```

Comment: First of why bothering writing Dict. Why not use std::map or similar container for your key value pairs. Second: In the second for loop you will invalidate your indices by removing from the vector you're iterating over.

Comment: its an exrecise for operator overloading, just to practice

Comment: Your operator seems to create a new Node then do an O(n) search for it (and other nodes with zero value). There are many things wrong. Why not just use std::map?

Comment: how can i bypass that?

Comment: Not to mention, if for some reason you can't use std::map as suggested by @Taron, using vectors to store the data doesn't seem optimal (in general).

Comment: Titus Winters says map (and unordered) map are inefficient by design and should not be used. std::vector<std::pair>> is so much better

Comment: your question has nothing to do with operator overloading. Operator overloading is just syntactic sugar. Your issue should are more fundamental.

Comment: Would be easier to help if there was a single .cpp file with all the source.  Also, does not compile.

Comment: im not using map becuase i am practiving operator overloading and cpp in general

Comment: @Treebeard A vector of pairs would perform better if you only inserted data at one point and then used it to access the elements. It will perform much worse if you need to add and remove nodes constantly, even though I agree std::map is not as fast as it could be (but there are alternative - faster - implementations around).

Comment: @Qubit There's always reasons to use everything, hence why they exist, but Yoav Linder says they're a learner so I wanted to put caution into the conversation. It's something I appreciated when I was starting out

Comment: The first call to the operator fails, if your Node<int> inits the value to 0. Then it is pushed in to the vector and gets removed by the second for loop. Then you return values.back() which is invalid since the values is empty

Comment: The second for loop in `operator[]` is very very strange. What's the purpose of it? I can't fix it if I don't know what it's trying to do.

Comment: The first problem I see is you are erasing ement zero when you’ve found element i and then you proceed to increment i even though the vector just got shorter, so you are skipping stuff.

Comment: i have edited the for loop, i missed the +i. and yes i want to remove all the keys elements that thier values are 0, but i dont know how

Comment: If you do the `+ i` and also do the `i++` as the for-loop increment, you'll skip checking the next key-value pair after the just-erased pair.

Comment: i have tried 3 hours to think how to bypass this issue but i just couldnt find a solution @Eljay

Comment: To be clear, one of your many problems here is that you add a default-constructed node, which will have a value of zero, then you attempt to remove it and then return a reference to the last element of an empty vector. That’s not the only issue. Step through it in a debugger and whatch what happens.

Comment: A dictionary that can only store things that can be compared to `0`, and that removes anything that compares equal to `0` on lookup seems very confusing to use.

Comment: Dictionary or no dictionary, your last `for` loop is not conceptually correct.  If you erase an item, the `i` index shouldn't be incremented.  You should take full control of `i` by making that a `while` loop or similar, and not have `i` automatically incremented using `for`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so hard, here's an iterator based solution.

```
auto i = keys.begin();
auto j = values.begin();
while (i != keys.end()) {
    if (j->value == 0) {
        i = keys.erase(i);
        j = values.erase(j);
    }
    else {
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }
}
```

But as has already been pointed out, if you add a Node with a value of zero you are going to erase the node you've just added and your program will fail. I guess the answer is to add the new key and value **after** this loop not before.

Comment: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: Step through it in a debugger.

Comment: @YoavLinder So you have a bug somewhere else in your code. In the long run it's better to learn how to debug by yourself.